# Hide Button if no URL entered

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, button

I have a problem with a Button.

When I enter no URl to a Post at my Side will show an Button "go to Site". But when I enter no URL the button is show.

Can anybody say me how I can hide the Button, if NO URL is entered?

Here is the Code from the Button:

```
<?php
/**
 * Coupon Code Box content - Generic/Promotion.
 *
 * @package Clipper\Templates
 * @author  AppThemes
 * @since   Clipper 1.6
 */
?>

<?php /*?><h5><?php _e( 'Promo:', RW_CP_TD ); ?></h5>
<?php */?>
<div class="couponAndTip">

<div class="link-holder">

    <a href="<?php echo clpr_get_coupon_out_url( $post ); ?>" id="coupon-link-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" 
    class="coupon-code-link affiliates-link" target="_blank" data-clipboard-text="<?php _e( 'Click to Redeem', RW_CP_TD ); ?>">
    <span><?php _e( 'Click to Redeem', RW_CP_TD ); ?></span></a>

</div> <!-- #link-holder -->

</div><!-- /couponAndTip -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3m2wtmjz/).

All you need to do is to replace the button id and input box id and add jQuery to your index page.

HTML:

```
<input id="input" type="text">
<button id="btn">Go to URL</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#input').on('keyup', function(){
    var visibility;
  if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
    visibility = 'inline';
  } else {
    visibility = 'none';
  }
    $('#btn').css('display', visibility);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * Coupon Code Box content - Coupon Code.
 *
 * @package Clipper\Templates
 * @author  AppThemes
 * @since   Clipper 1.6
 */
global $clpr_options;

$coupon_code = wptexturize( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'clpr_coupon_code', true ) );
$button_text = ( $clpr_options->coupon_code_hide ) ? __( 'Show Coupon', RW_CP_TD ) : $coupon_code;?>

<?php if(clpr_get_coupon_out_url( $post ) != '') : ?>

<div class="couponAndTip">
 <div class="link-holder">
    <a href="<?php echo clpr_get_coupon_out_url( $post ); ?>" id="coupon-link-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="coupon-code-link test" target="_blank" data-clipboard-text="<?php echo $coupon_code; ?>">
        <span><?php echo $button_text; ?></span>
    </a>
 </div> <!-- #link-holder -->
</div><!-- /couponAndTip -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Just put that control structure to check if that url is not empty

Comment: The logic should be same, just check that value before printing the html

Comment: So i have test it, but now my Theme loads only teh half op page an then white screen. :(

Comment: I'm sorry add a question mark at the closing php <?php endif; ?>

Comment: Now the white Page error is resolved, but the Button is showing...

ok.. i think the "single-coupon.php" is the problem too, because the is the Code "<?php clpr_coupon_code_box(); ?>"

for example.. this is the "single-coupon.php" http://test.premium-lizenz.com/-/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/

Comment: I don't understand anything what you are saying :P

Comment: okay.. again..

i have one File called "content-codebox.php" in this File is the Code in my Question Post.

i tested the Variables "<?php if(clpr_get_coupon_out_url( $post ) != '') : ?>" and "<?php endif; ?>" but the Result was not changed.

so i look deeper and see the File called "single-coupon.php" has the Variable "<?php clpr_coupon_code_box(); ?>".

you understand now what i want say?

Comment: no xD just get the correct variable of that URL that returns empty and put it in the if condition